# DataBind only if PostBack failed

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a lot of places in my code, which look like:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindAllRepeaters(); // heavy (up to 1 min).
}

protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DoSomething(... user input .....))
        Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");

    ShowError();
}
```

You may notice, data from `Repeater`s are not used on postback anywhere if  `DoSomething(...)` is successful, but it takes up to 1 minute to load it in Page_Init on every click. Is there any elegant technique to avoid this?

Of course, I know about `IsPostBack`, but then I have to call `DataBindAllRepeaters()` many times: on `Page_Init` and at the end of every click handler?

Answer (score 0):

If it takes one minute to databind your repeater you show too much data. You should try to optimize your queries anyway. However, since the values are stored in `ViewState` by default you don't need to databind them on every postback.

Therefore use the `IsPostBack` property to check it:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        DataBindAllRepeaters(); // heavy (up to 1 min).
}
```

> Of course, I know about IsPostBack, but then I have to call
>   DataBindAllRepeaters() many times: on Page_Init and at the end of
>   every click handler?

No, you don't need to databind the in the event handler. You should not depend on the datasource in the events. If you have to identify a record you just need it's primary key value which can be stored in various ways.

Comment: This is statistics page in my admin panel. It is calculated on-the-fly. I disabled ViewState for all my website long time ago - I have nested `Repeater`s with `DropDownList`s etc., and it produces giant base64 string. So I bind data on every page reload.

Comment: @Denis: so you see that disabling viewstate does not mean that you get better performance. However, it still doesnt explain why you think that you need to "call DataBindAllRepeaters() many times: on Page_Init and at the end of every click handler".